# The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, linq, msbuild, resources, resharper

Today I installed the free trial of ReSharper to clean up an application in Visual Studio 2015.

I have always built this application by using `alt + b + h` which is the same as choosing `Build -> Publish AppName`, and this is usually pretty reliable when it comes to producing an EXE, ready to use.

However, after doing some cleaning up (mainly LINQ queries, renames and deleting no-longer-used methods/fields), I see this error when try to publish:

```
Error       The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(MemoryStream stream)
   at System.Drawing.Image.System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo si, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph)
   at System.Resources.ResourceWriter.WriteValue(ResourceTypeCode typeCode, Object value, BinaryWriter writer, IFormatter objFormatter)
   at System.Resources.ResourceWriter.Generate()
   at System.Resources.ResourceWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Resources.ResourceWriter.Close()
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.WriteResources(IResourceWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.WriteResources(String filename)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.ProcessFile(String inFile, String outFile)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.Run(TaskLoggingHelper log, ITaskItem[] assemblyFilesList, ArrayList inputs, ArrayList outputs, Boolean sourcePath, String language, String namespacename, String resourcesNamespace, String filename, String classname, Boolean publicClass)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.Run(TaskLoggingHelper log, ITaskItem[] assemblyFilesList, ArrayList inputs, ArrayList outputs, Boolean sourcePath, String language, String namespacename, String resourcesNamespace, String filename, String classname, Boolean publicClass)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.OutOfProcTaskAppDomainWrapperBase.InstantiateAndExecuteTask(IBuildEngine oopTaskHostNode, LoadedType taskType, String taskName, String taskLocation, String taskFile, Int32 taskLine, Int32 taskColumn, AppDomainSetup appDomainSetup, IDictionary`2 taskParams)  ITHelpre
```

And no output is generated.

I have restarted VS with no effect, and have also noticed that I was able to build the project by opening `Developer Command Prompt for VS2015` and running `"msbuild C:/path/to/solution.sln"`.

This did create an EXE in the right place, but whenever I try opening it I get

`Appname has stopped working - Windows is collecting more information about the problem. This might take several minutes...`

Does anyone have any tips as to how I can get to the bottom of this?

**Extra Details**

After looking at the Form Designer in VS, I can see that one of my images is corrupted (the colours have changed and lots of lines and marks which weren't there before)

Removing a couple of images I found which looked corrupted, the project built, but still crashes on execution

Comment: Did you make any modifications to your project's image resources?

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot No the only changes I made were in the code and related to variable names or the order of ifstatements/forloops

Comment: Just guessing from your "extra details", but I would assume that corrupted image is your culprit. Have you tried removing it and building without it? If that is successful, re-add the image from the original, or an older commit if available.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot That worked! I removed 2 resource images which looked like they were glitching out, and the project built, but when I execute the app it still crashes on launch. Will try re-adding the images and try again - thanks!

Comment: Does it crash when launched from VS, or only when you run it as a standalone EXE?

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot After replacing the images with some new, plain pngs, the application works fine again. Will add an answer to this later on today - many thanks for your help

Comment: It was crashing when running as standalaone EXE, and I noticed it threw an exception when debugging in the Resource Designer!

Comment: I did at some point add my pageControl class the the AppName namespace, which seems have had an effect, as the exception was thrown when the program was referring to the pageControl variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running in debug mode I noticed it was throwing an exception in the Resource Designer when `PageControl` was being called (even though it had already been declared).

This seems to have happened after changing this:

```
Class PageControl1
{
    // Code goes here
}
```

To this:

```
namespace AppName
{
    Class PageControl1
    {
        // Code goes here
    }
}
```

Which I don't quite understand - to me it makes sense that a class being used by the application should live in the same namespace as all the other classes used in that application. I would very much appreciate any insight into this.

After changing `PageControl1` back to how it looked originally, I removed the 2 corrupted images (which appear to have become corrupt straight after making the above `namespace` change, and replaced them with some new images, and this solved my problem.